# what are the different ways in which a method can be overridden in java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

Edit:My question is what different access modifiers, return type and argument list can be used in the subclass method so that the superclass method with same name is overridden?

Comment: As long as a method has the same name as a parent method, but doesn't have the same argument types in the same order, a subclass method overloads a superclass method. But maybe you mean *override*, which is completely different. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 3):

Method overloading in Java occurs when two or more methods in the same class have the exact same name but different parameters.

But, i suppose you mean override since you're talking about inheritance :

In Java, a method is only overrided when a subclass has a method with the **same signature**.

A method signature consists only of the **name** of the method and the **parameters types and their order**.

Comment: sorry for misspelling overriding as overloading. what i want to know is can the access modifier(public, private, final etc) can be different in the overridden method?

Comment: @Amina .. A method signature consists only of the name of the method,  parameter types, order and **number**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload a method by changing the return value (although you can override and specialize it) or by access modifiers (although you can override it and make it "more accessible"). Only the argument list can be used to overload a method.